# custom property for "link" backend

Tags: org-mode

The callback api for a `link` type in an `org-mode` backend looks something like this

```
(defun org-leanpub-link (link contents info)
  ...
)
```

I can get the standard properties for a link element, such as

```
(org-export-get-caption
 (org-export-get-parent-element link))
```

and I could access custom properties like this

```
(message "%s" (org-element-property
               :foo
               (org-export-get-parent-element link)))
```

except I do not know how to add any extra information to the link in the `org-mode` file!

How can I add custom markup to a link, such that I can have access to it in my custom backend? I need to be able to provide a custom width for the output format.

Comment: latex is able to use `ATTR_LATEX` for this... but I'm not sure how to use `ATTR`s in my own backend.